# Extract specific tags and bundle remaining into one in HTML

Tags: html, regex, beautifulsoup, regex-greedy

So lets say, in a HTML snippet, I have some `non-table` tags, then a `<table>` tag, then some `non-table` tags, then another `<table>` tag and so on.

What I wanna do is get the first set of non-table tags into one group, then the table section in another and the next set of non-table tags into another and so on.

I have tried using regex. It is becoming superly complicated. I have tried searching how to do using BeautifulSoup but no use.

And also, if I have to extend it to ordered `<ol>` and unordered `<ul>` sections, how can I do it?

For example: I have this (HTML) string:

```
<h2>Hello There.</h2>\n
<p>
<a href="http://abc/">Click ME</a> </p>
<p>Lets have a coffee</p>\n
<table>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>Drink</th><th>Cost</th></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
        <td>Coffee</td><td>152.61 </td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Coke</td><td>62.56</td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Pepsi</td><td>21.71</td> </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>
So? <a href="http://abc/">click me too</a>. Here is another list</p>
<table>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>Food</th><th>cost</th></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
        <td>Bhel</td><td>25.5</td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Puri</td><td>23.0</td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Something</td><td>19.4</td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Pani</td><td>17.12 </td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Puriya</td><td>10.64 </td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Done</td><td>9.21</td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Rice</td><td>9.20 </td> </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>This amazing collection is here.</p>
```

Required Result:

```
[<h2>Hello There.</h2>
<p>
<a href="http://abc/">Click ME</a> </p>
<p>Lets have a coffee</p>, 

<table>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>Drink</th><th>Cost</th></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
        <td>Coffee</td><td>152.61 </td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Coke</td><td>62.56</td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Pepsi</td><td>21.71</td> </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>,
<p>
So? <a href="http://abc/">click me too</a>. Here is another list</p>, 
<table>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>Food</th><th>cost</th></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
        <td>Bhel</td><td>25.5</td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Puri</td><td>23.0</td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Something</td><td>19.4</td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Pani</td><td>17.12 </td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Puriya</td><td>10.64 </td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Done</td><td>9.21</td> </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Rice</td><td>9.20 </td> </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>,
<p>This amazing collection is here.</p>]
```

a list containing the parts

Comment: post html code or url and the output you want

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: is this fine? @宏杰李

Comment: Required result is not a valid Python list. Do the correction.

Comment: done correction

Comment: You should also remove the superfluous newline characters `\n` from the HTML code as well.

Comment: ok. done, please check now